# How to get max length record from List<String>?

Tags: c#, list

I have List contain list of string records. I want to get record whose length is maximum in all the records.
How can I get max length record from the List?

Comment: Straightforward solution: iterate over list and compare current record length with previously found maximum. Have you tried it?

Comment: Also, have you tried copying your *exact* question title into google?

Comment: `list.Select(c => c.Length).Max()` or something?

Comment: What if there are multiple with the same length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find all longest strings:

```
IEnumerable<string> longestStrings = list
    .GroupBy(str => str == null ? 0 : str.Length)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key) // order by length
    .First();
```

Another approach which might be cheaper in terms of memory consumption:

```
int maxLength = list.Max(str=> str == null ? 0 : str.Length); 
longestStrings = list
    .Where(str => (str == null ? 0 : str.Length) == maxLength);
```

Comment: If the input is a list where double-enumeration is cheap, I'd rather use a two pass approach. First `Max` then `Where(len==max)`

Answer (score 3):

This might do the trick for you

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add("001");
strings.Add("00121");
strings.Add("001123123");
strings.Add("00144");


string longest = strings.OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).First();
```